# Remove the last element of an array while the sum of the array is bigger than a specific number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the last items of an array as long as the sum of the array is higher than a limit. The code I have works but seems to cause slow downs or crash.
I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

```js
let array = [166, 157, 251, 171, 191];
let limit = 400;

for (
  let sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b); sum > limit; sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
) {
  array.pop();
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This solution will achieve the result in `O(n)`

You can achieve the result If you loop over the `array` and remember the last total i.e `currentTotal` and stop the iteration and `break` out from the loop if

```
currentTotal + val > limit
```

else add the current value in `currentTotal` and push that element in the `result` array.

```js
let array = [166, 157, 251, 171, 191];
let limit = 400;

let currentTotal = 0;
const result = [];

for (let val of array) {
  if (currentTotal + val > limit) {
    break;
  }
  result.push(val);
  currentTotal += val;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to sum the entire array each time through the loop. Calculate the sum once at the beginning. Then subtract the element that you removed from the sum.

```js
let array = [166, 157, 251, 171, 191];
let limit = 400;

for (let sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b); sum > limit; sum -= array.pop()) {}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

To improve efficiency, as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69060410/4778654) stated, you can calculate the sum once and update it in each loop iteration. I believe a `while` loop expresses this idea the most clearly:

```js
const arr = [166, 157, 251, 171, 191];
const limit = 400;

let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
while (sum > limit) {
  const lastNum = arr.pop();
  sum -= lastNum;
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const threshold = 10;
let sum = 0;
arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3];
const filteredArray = arr.filter((el) => {
  sum += el;
  return sum <= threshold;
});
```